# Socket.io, redis and redis message queue

Tags: ios, node.js, sockets

I am using SocketIO and redis based on the following code,

```
var sub = redis.createClient();
var pub = redis.createClient();
sub.subscribe('chat');
io.use(socketHandshake({store: sessionStore, key:'jsessionid', secret:'secret', parser:cookieParser()}));
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('chat', function (message) {
        // io.emit('chat', "hello world");
        pub.publish('chat', "hello world");
    });
    sub.on('message', function (channel, message) {
        io.emit(channel, message);
    });
});
```

This is the base code. I have modified the code so that if any user goes offline, in server side I am storing the messages in RSMQ(Redis Simple Message Queue) and when user comes online, the message is fetched from queue and emits to the user.I have used the following code to achieve this.I have stored the user status in an array.

```
 var fs = require('fs')
    , http = require('http')
    , socketio = require('socket.io');
var redis = require('redis'); 
var store = redis.createClient();
var pub = redis.createClient();
var sub = redis.createClient(); 
RedisSMQ = require("rsmq");
rsmq = new RedisSMQ( {host: "127.0.0.1", port: 6379, ns: "rsmq"} );
var active_users=[];
var inactive_users=[];  
var user_status=[];
var channel_users=[];
var users_queue=[];
var socket_ids=[];
var cname,qn;
var clients=[];
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-type': 'text/html'});
    res.end(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/index.html'));
}).listen(9000, function() {
    console.log('Listening at: http://localhost:9000');
});
socketio.listen(server).on('connection', function (socket) {    
    socket.on('login', function(data){
    console.log('a user ' + data.userId + ' connected'+socket.id);
    //saving userId to array with socket ID
    active_users[socket.id] = data.userId;
    socket_ids[data.userId]=socket.id;
    clients[socket.id] = socket;
    user_status[data.userId]="online";
  });
    socket.on('message', function (msg) {        
        console.log('Message Received: ', msg);
        socket.broadcast.emit('message', msg);
    });
    socket.on('json', function (msg) {       
        if(msg.channel_name=='UserState'){
            rsmq.listQueues(function(err,resp){
         //console.log("QUEUES LIST"+resp);
        });
            if(msg.user_state=='active'){
              store.hmset("active_users."+msg.sender_id,{"user":"online"});
              user_status[msg.sender_id]="online";console.log(user_status);

              if(users_queue[msg.sender_id]!=undefined && users_queue[msg.sender_id].length>0){
                console.log("USERS QUEUE:"+users_queue[msg.sender_id]['0']);
              for(var i=0;i<users_queue[msg.sender_id].length;i++){
                cname=users_queue[msg.sender_id][i].split('_')[0];//get channel name from queue name
                qn=users_queue[msg.sender_id][i];
              rsmq.getQueueAttributes({qname:users_queue[msg.sender_id][i]},function(err,resp){

                 console.log("RESP:"+resp.msgs);
                 if(resp.msgs>0){    //if there are messages in queue......
                 for(var j=0;j<resp.msgs;j++){                    
                 rsmq.popMessage({qname:qn},function(err,resp){

                    console.log(resp);
                    var sid=socket_ids[msg.sender_id]; console.log("SOCKETID:"+sid); //get socket.id for the user
                    pub.publish(cname,resp.message);

                   });
                } 
                }
                });
              }
          }
            }
            else{
              store.hmset("active_users."+msg.sender_id,{"status":"offline"});  
              user_status[msg.sender_id]="offline"; 
            }
        }
        if(msg.channel_name=='ShareConversation'){
            var channel=msg.conversations_data.conversation_id;//have to change to conversation_id or whatever channel.....
            sub.subscribe(channel);
            channel_users[channel]=[];
            var m=msg.conversations_data.users.split(',');    
            for(var i=0;i<m.length;i++){

            channel_users[channel].push(m[i]);
            }

            for(var i=0;i<channel_users[channel].length;i++){
                var q=channel_users[channel][i].split('@')[0].replace(/(^\s+|\s+$)/g, '');
                var queue_name=channel+"_"+q;console.log(queue_name);
                var uname=channel_users[channel][i].replace(/(^\s+|\s+$)/g, '');
                users_queue[uname]=[];
                users_queue[uname].push(queue_name);                

                    rsmq.createQueue({qname:queue_name}, function (err, resp) {
                    console.log(err);
                    console.log(queue_name);
                        if (resp===1) {
                            console.log("queue created");
                        }
                    });
            }

        }
        socket.broadcast.emit('json', msg);
    });
    sub.on('message', function (channel, message) {

        console.log("Message: " + message);
        for(var i=0;i<channel_users[channel].length;i++){
            var c=channel_users[channel][i].replace(/(^\s+|\s+$)/g, '');console.log("channel_users:"+channel_users[channel][i]);console.log("USER STATE :"+ user_status[c]);
            if(user_status[c]=='offline'){
                //send notification.........
                //put messages in queue.......
                var q=channel_users[channel][i].split('@')[0].replace(/(^\s+|\s+$)/g, '');
                var queue_name=channel+"_"+q;console.log(queue_name);
                rsmq.sendMessage({qname:queue_name, message:message}, function (err, resp) {
                    console.log(err);
                    if (resp) {
                        console.log("Message sent. ID:", resp);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
      socket.emit(channel, message);
    });      
});
```

This is my entire code. Here the issue is when the user goes offline, the message gets saved in queue multiple times and when the user comes online, the messages are received multiple times as there are duplicate messages saved in queue. How to overcome this.Please help....